# boost hana zip two sequences into map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

```
static constexpr auto type_tuple_c = hana::tuple_t<T...>;
static constexpr auto idx_tuple_c = hana::tuple_c<std::size_t, 0, sizeof...(T)>;
```

I'd like to map these two sequences of equal sizes with each other.  However, I can't seem to understand how to get that with the `hana::map` features:

```
static constexpr auto type_idx_map_c = hana::unpack(
    hana::zip_with(hana::make_pair, type_tuple_c, idx_tuple_c)
  , hana::make_map
);
```

No matter what transformations I make, I can't seem to create the mapping.  I understand that a map requires its elements to be of the Product concept, but I can't seem to get (or even understand) that behavior in regards to zipped structures.

Is there anything I can do, or anything I'm doing incorrectly?

Running `gcc version 6.0.0 20160320` and `hana version 0.7.0` last fetched today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'd like to map these two sequences of equal sizes with each other.

Those sequences aren't typically of equal sizes. `type_tuple_c` has size `sizeof...(T)`, but `idx_tuple_c` has size 2 - it only contains the elements `hana::size_c<0>` and `hana::size_c<sizeof...(T)>`.

I think what you're looking for as far as indices go is just `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{}`. That should still play well with Boost.Hana.

Comment: Ahh that makes so much sense... and explains why one of my test cases passed.  Thanks!  Also, I chose to use `hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::range_c<size_t, 0, sizeof...(T)>)` for those interested.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez why that instead of `make_index_sequence`?